# TooManyRedirects Error with requests module

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Currently trying to get html for url and am encountering an error raised by the requests module in python.

What's the preferred method for handling the TooManyRedirects Error raised by requests? How do access the html for the site?

```
site = requests.get("http://www.hortonworks.com/blog/data-science-apacheh-hadoop-predicting-airline-delays")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal way to disallow redirects is to use `allow_redirects=False`
For eg.,

```
site = requests.get(url,allow_redirects=False)
```

But that is **NOT** the solution to your problem,

Adding a user-agent solves the redirect issue and gets the page-source successfully.

Try this,

```
headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"}

url="http://www.hortonworks.com/blog/data-science-apacheh-hadoop-predicting-airline-delays"

site = requests.get(url,headers=headers)    
print site.url
```

-

```
Out[]: 'http://hortonworks.com/blog/data-science-apacheh-hadoop-predicting-airline-delays/'
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Can you explain why adding headers solved the issue?

Comment: @mwoods there could be many reason, the best I can guess is that hortonworks do not like someone scraping their website. Using the default user agent of Python is an indication to that. Using the user agent as stated above in my answer fakes the request to appear as if its coming from Chrome/Mozilla which makes it normal.