# TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects

Tags: python, web-scraping, error-handling

can somenone give me a hint how to fix the error - TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.?

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = 'https://www.roco.cc/'

headers = {
'UserAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'
}

productlinks = []

for x in range(1,2):
r = requests.get(
f'https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives.html?p={x}&verfuegbarkeit_status=41%2C42%2C43%2C45%2C44')

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
productlist = soup.find_all('li', class_='item product product-item')

for item in productlist:
    for link in item.find_all('a', class_='product-item-link', href=True):
        productlinks.append(link['href'])
```

for link in productlinks:

```
r = requests.get(link, headers={'user-agent': 'My app'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

Manufacturer_name = 'Roco'

try:
    Reference = soup.find('span', class_='product-head-artNr').text.strip()
except:
    Reference = ''
    
try:  
    Price = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Price'}).text.strip()
except:
    Price = ''
    
Type = 'Steam locomotive'
    
try:
    Scale = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Scale'}).text.strip()
except:
    Scale = ''

try:  
    Current = soup.find('Current').text.strip()
except:
    Current = ''


try:  
    Control = soup.find('td', {'data-th':'Control'}).text.strip()
except:
    Control = ''

try:
    Interface = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Interface'}).text.strip()
except:
    Interface = ''

try:
    Digital_decoder = soup.find(
        'td', {'data-th': 'Digital decoder'}).text.strip()
except:
    Digital_decoder = ''

try:
    Decoder_Type = soup.find(
        'td', {'data-th': 'Decoder-Type'}).text.strip()
except:
    Decoder_Type = ''

try:
    Motor = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Motor'}).text.strip()
except:
    Motor = ''

try:
    Flywheel = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Flywheel'}).text.strip()
except:
    Flywheel = ''

try:
    Minimum_radius = soup.find(
        'td', {'data-th': 'Minimum radius'}).text.strip()
except:
    Minimum_radius = ''

try:
    Length_over_buffer = soup.find(
        'td', {'data-th': 'Length over buffer'}).text.strip()
except:
    Length_over_buffer = ''

try:
    Number_of_driven_axles = soup.find(
    'td', {'data-th': 'Number of  driven axles'}).text.strip()
except:
    Number_of_driven_axles = ''

try:
    Number_of_axles_with_traction_tyres = soup.find(
    'td', {'data-th': 'Number of  axles with traction tyres'}).text.strip()
except:
    Number_of_axles_with_traction_tyres = ''

try:
    Coupling = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Coupling'}).text.strip()
except:
    Coupling = ''

try:
    LED_lighting = soup.find(
        'td', {'data-th': 'LED lighting'}).text.strip()
except:
    LED_lighting = ''

try:
    Head_light = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Head light'}).text.strip()
except:
    Head_light = ''

try:
    LED_head_light = soup.find(
        'td', {'data-th': 'LED head light'}).text.strip()
except:
    LED_head_light = ''

try:
    Country = soup.find(
        'td', {'data-th': 'Original (country)'}).text.strip()
except:
    Country = ''

try:
    Railway_company = soup.find(
        'td', {'data-th': 'Railway Company'}).text.strip()
except:
    Railway_company = ''

try:
    Epoch = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Epoch'}).text.strip()
except:
    Epoch = ''

try:
    Description = soup.find(
        'div', class_='product-add-form-text').text.strip()
except:
    Description = ''


Locomotives = {
    Manufacturer_name: 'Manufacturer_name',
    Reference: 'Reference',
    Price: 'Price',
    Type: 'Type',
    Scale: 'Scale',
    Current: 'Current',
    Control: 'Control',
    Interface: 'Interface',
    Digital_decoder: 'Digital_decoder',
    Decoder_Type: 'Decoder_Type',
    Motor: 'Motor',
    Flywheel: 'Flywheel',
    Minimum_radius: 'Minimum_radius',
    Length_over_buffer: 'Length_over_buffer',
    Number_of_driven_axles: 'Number_of_driven_axles',
    Number_of_axles_with_traction_tyres: 'Number_of_axles_with_traction_tyres',
    Coupling: 'Coupling',
    LED_lighting: 'LED_lighting',
    Head_light: 'Head_light',
    LED_head_light: 'LED_head_light',
    Country: 'Country',
    Railway_company: 'Railway_company',
    Epoch: 'Epoch',
    Description: 'Description',
} 

print(Locomotives)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766515/toomanyredirects-error-with-requests-module

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

baseurl = 'https://www.roco.cc/'

headers = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

productlinks = []

for x in range(1,2):
    r = requests.get(
        f'https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives.html?p={x}&verfuegbarkeit_status=41%2C42%2C43%2C45%2C44')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    productlist = soup.find_all('li', class_='item product product-item')
    
    for item in productlist:
        for link in item.find_all('a', class_='product-item-link', href=True):
            productlinks.append(link['href'])

Loco_list = []

for link in productlinks:
    r = requests.get(link, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    Manufacturer_name = 'Roco'

    try:
        Reference = soup.find('span', class_='product-head-artNr').text.strip()
    except:
        Reference = ''
        
    try:  
        Price = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Price'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Price = ''
        
    Type = 'Steam locomotive'
        
    try:
        Scale = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Scale'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Scale = ''

    try:  
        Current = soup.find('Current').text.strip()
    except:
        Current = ''


    try:  
        Control = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Control'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Control = ''

    try:
        Interface = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Interface'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Interface = ''

    try:
        Digital_decoder = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'Digital decoder'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Digital_decoder = ''

    try:
        Decoder_Type = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'Decoder-Type'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Decoder_Type = ''

    try:
        Motor = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Motor'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Motor = ''

    try:
        Flywheel = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Flywheel'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Flywheel = ''

    try:
        Minimum_radius = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'Minimum radius'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Minimum_radius = ''

    try:
        Length_over_buffer = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'Length over buffer'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Length_over_buffer = ''

    try:
        Number_of_driven_axles = soup.find(
        'td', {'data-th': 'Number of  driven axles'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Number_of_driven_axles = ''

    try:
        Number_of_axles_with_traction_tyres = soup.find(
        'td', {'data-th': 'Number of  axles with traction tyres'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Number_of_axles_with_traction_tyres = ''

    try:
        Coupling = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Coupling'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Coupling = ''

    try:
        LED_lighting = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'LED lighting'}).text.strip()
    except:
        LED_lighting = ''

    try:
        Head_light = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Head light'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Head_light = ''

    try:
        LED_head_light = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'LED head light'}).text.strip()
    except:
        LED_head_light = ''

    try:
        Country = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'Original (country)'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Country = ''

    try:
        Railway_company = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'Railway Company'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Railway_company = ''

    try:
        Epoch = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Epoch'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Epoch = ''

    try:
        Description = soup.find(
            'div', class_='product-add-form-text').text.strip()
    except:
        Description = ''


    Locomotives = {
        'Manufacturer_name': Manufacturer_name,
        'Reference': Reference,
        'Price': Price,
        'Type': Type,
        'Scale': Scale,
        'Current': Current,
        'Control': Control,
        'Interface': Interface,
        'Digital_decoder': Digital_decoder,
        'Decoder_Type': Decoder_Type,
        'Motor': Motor,
        'Flywheel': Flywheel,
        'Minimum_radius': Minimum_radius,
        'Length_over_buffer': Length_over_buffer,
        'Number_of_driven_axles': Number_of_driven_axles,
        'Number_of_axles_with_traction_tyres': Number_of_axles_with_traction_tyres,
        'Coupling': Coupling,
        'LED_lighting': LED_lighting,
        'Head_light': Head_light,
        'LED_head_light': LED_head_light,
        'Country': Country,
        'Railway_company': Railway_company,
        'Epoch': Epoch,
        'Description': Description,
    } 

    Loco_list.append(Locomotives)
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(Loco_list)
# df2 = pd.DataFrame()
# df3 = pd.DataFrame()
# df4 = pd.DataFrame()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Roco - locomotives.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Model')
# df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Spare parts')
# df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Documents')
# df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Photos')
writer.save()

print('Saved to file')
```

Comment: It's awesome that you answered your own question! Could you provide a bit of explanation on what your new code does so future users that come here will be able to figure out their issues?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).